# NSNotification centre to observe whether an application is opened through URL Scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter, uiapplicationdelegate, url-scheme

I have a class which will make `NSNotificationCenter` to observe whether the app is active or it went to background and it will do a set of actions according to that.

I want to set a `NSNotificationCenter` to observe whether the app is opened through URL scheme .

This is what I tried:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[self class] selector:@selector(appOpenedThroughUrl:) name:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey object:nil];
```

But its not getting called when the app opens through URL please provide me some idea to do the same.

I don't want to use the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

+(void)appOpenedThroughUrl:(NSNotification *)notification { 
  NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo); 
}
```

Comment: can you add ur method  appOpenedThroughUrl:  also?

Comment: +(void)appOpenedThroughUrl:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    
    NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo);
    
}

Answer (score 2):

you need to post notification whenever it open through custom url scheme
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey object:self];

Comment: where i have to place this code ? will that notify myapp when it opens through url without writing anything inside  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url    ??

Comment: yes you need to post notification inside this code  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{ [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey object:self];}

Comment: where i have to add ? please make sure your answers are clear

Comment: when your application is open through the url scheme then - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url get called inside this function you can post the notifications and make sure you have added the observer before posting notification.